# Nginx Lua module for redirecting based on proxy and access headers

Tags: nginx, lua

In nginx I want to redirect user based on access and proxy headers. When I put it to the response header, they are shown correctly in the browser. But when using in lua to redirect with an `if` it does not.

For user with access app creates string `isprotectedfalse` and for guests I get `isprotected`

```
        add_header X-User-Access-Flag  $userinfo$arg_limit$upstream_http_x_doc_protection; #this works
        if ($http_x_user_access_flag = "isprotected") { #this doesnt
          return 302 $scheme://$http_host$uri?limit=true;
        }
```

and similar code but in lua:

```
             rewrite_by_lua_block {
                local params = ngx.req.get_uri_args()
                local limit = params["limit"]
                local headers = ngx.resp.get_headers()
                local useraccesss = headers["X-User-Access-Flag"]
                if useraccesss == "isprotected" and limit == nil then
                    local delimiter = (ngx.var.is_args == "" or ngx.var.is_args == nil) and "?" or "&"
                    local new_url = ngx.var.request_uri .. delimiter .. "limit=true" 
                    return ngx.redirect(new_url)
                end
             }
```

why is it not redirecting as expected?

Edit:
From using `header_filter_by_lua_block`

I have manage to access them from `ngx.var['upstream_http_x_user_access_flag']` which is used before the lua block to set X-User-Access-Flag (from proxy_pass). But sadly server errors on redirection try. Seems at this point headers are already sent (but I am still able to set a custom header there?! so this is confusing.

I can not access such `ngx.var` from `rewrite_by_lua_block` as this has not performed `proxy_pass` yet. How could I access this variables `after` auth and `proxy_pass` and redirect based on aquired headers?

Comment: You are using `$upstream_` variable, but rewrite directives execute before proxying and `$upstream_` variables are not available at this time. For lua you probably could use `body_filter_by_lua_block`/`header_filter_by_lua_block`. Or, maybe, you need something simpler like `auth_request`.

Comment: switching `header_filter_by_lua_block` does not change anything. Should it be available there?

Comment: I have manage to access them from `ngx.var['upstream_http_x_user_access_flag']` which is used before the lua block to set `X-User-Access-Flag`.
But sadly server errors on redirection try. Seems at this point headers are already send (but I am still able to set a custom `header` there, so this is confusing. 
I can not access such `ngx.var` from `rewrite_by_lua_block`.
How could I access and redirect?